# Custom X axis for line graph on confluence

Tags: pandas, csv, graph, charts, confluence

I want a line graph ordered by software build to show the performance of a specific API endpoint on Confluence. Seems easy right?

I'm using python & pandas to generate a csv to be uploaded to the page, the CSV macro to present the data and the Chart From Table macro to create the chart.

Sample data set for endpoint with **Run** as the index:

```
Run,     Response Time
build_1, 0.051
build_2, 0.068
build_3, 0.059
```

On the chart macro in Confluence if I set 
**X-axis value column** = **Run** 
& **Y-axis value column** = **Response Time** 
I get one point on the graph located at X=0,Y= < some random number unrelated to my data set >

I checked to make sure that the csv is interpreting my build number as a string, I'm sorting builds before exporting the csv to avoid doing it on the page itself, changed every single knob imaginable in the table macro, I just cant win here. Can someone please enlighten me?

Comment: 'Run' is already set as the index for the table

Comment: Apologies.  I must have misunderstood.

Comment: no worries, glad you brought it up. I made some edits to make it more clear :)